# Finding matrix corresponding to linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> A linear transformation acts on $R^2$ by first doubling the $x$-coordinate and then rotating the plane by an angle of $\pi/2$ ($90^{\circ}$) counter-clockwise. What is the corresponding matrix to this linear transformation?

Comment: Well, can you at least figure out the matrix for the doubling transformation? We can take care of rotation later.

Comment: I can do the rotation not the doubling

Comment: is it 2*([0,-1] [1,0])

Comment: where do your principle compenent vecors ($\hat i, \hat j$, or $(1,0), (0,1)$ depending on your notation preference) go in this transformation?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: If you did this transformation to the vector $(1,0)$ where does it go?  first it gets doubled $(2,0),$  then it rotates 90 degrees $(0,2).$ What about  $(0,1)$?  We are not doubling vertically, so nothing there.  And it rotates 90.  $(-1,0).$  So you need a matrix that takes these principal vectors to their new coordinates.

Comment: i did not do the transformation on (1,0). I basically stated that for any vector to become doubled and rotate 90 multiply by this.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Any linear transformation of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is fully determined by where it sends the standard basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^2$, namely $i=[1,0]$ and $j=[0,1]$. Can you determine what happens to these basis vectors under your linear transformation? Also, if you know what happens to these basis vectors, do you know how to find the matrix corresponding to that linear transformation in that basis?